# AttributeError error while trying to split an array of numbers

Tags: python, arrays

I created an array `arr1 = [25, 26]`. When I try to split the array on the basis on comma using the statement `array1 = arr1.split(',')`, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
    array1 = arr1.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: What is your expected result of this *split the array*?

Comment: `split` is [a method of `str`ing objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) - what are you expecting `[25, 26].split(',')` to **do**, exactly?! `str.split` is for making strings into lists - what you have is **already a list**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr1 = [25,26]` First `arr1` is not an array its a `list` object.

Second `split` is not a part a `list`'s attributes so can't use `split` function with list object.

You can see all `list` attributes using `dir` built-in function.

```
>>> dir([])
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__',
 '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__set
attr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert'
, 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

That is why you are getting `AttributeError` excecption because you are applying `split` function on a list object which is not a part of `list`'s attributes.

Answer (score -1):

split() is not applicable for list items. It is applicable for string types.

In your case you need not to do split.

its simple you can use --

for item in arr1:
    print item

If you want to check lenght of the array. You can do - **len(arra1)**

In python there is no data type array. Its a list.

To check data type just use - **type(arr1)**